# Can't load data in Windows PgAdmin using SQL

Tags: pgadmin

I am trying to load data from Gordon Linhoff's book "Data Analysis Using SQL and EXCEL" into a PostGres db via pgadmin on a Windows 10 system using the an SQL script file.  Part of the SQL script is

```
CREATE TABLE Customers (
    CustomerId int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    HouseholdId int NOT NULL,
    Gender varchar(50) NOT NULL,
    FirstName varchar(50) NOT NULL
) ;

COPY Customers FROM 'R:/Shared/AG_LW_Shared/Data_Analysis/Customers.txt'
    WITH HEADER NULL 'NULL' DELIMITER ' ' CSV;
```

Unfortunately, I get this error:

```
ERROR:  could not open file "R:/Shared/AG_LW_Shared/Data_Analysis/Calendar.txt" for reading: No such file or directory
```

The file does exist on the system, so I suspect this is an issue with filename syntax.  I have changed case to match with the case in the Windows directory but got the same error message.  All suggestions gratefully received - thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This issue seems to have been resolved by changing the root directory from R: to C: